# What is pod to pod encryption in kubernetes? And How to implement pod to pod encryption by using mTLS in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I want to implement pod to pod encryption by use of mTLS. And Another one how can I
Modify TLS encryption between the apiserver and etcd pods

Comment: I want to see your attempts ? your research ? where do you reach ? this website is for fixing issues not for generating ideas and implementing things from scratch

Comment: I don't want the implementation from the scratch, I want to know how to proceed this, just an overview of it. Because I didn't get proper information from the web

Comment: Can you ask these questions separately?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a service mesh such as istio or linkerd. Service mesh provides mTLS between pods and you don't need to implement it yourself.Service meshe deploys a sidecar such as envoy along with your pod and the sidecar takes care of TLS termination with mTLS enabled between pods.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#auto-mutual-tls