# kubernetes TLS communication between pods (lighter solution)

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, https, kubectl

I am adding security to my cluster. One of the requirements is that the communication between pods is secure.

The most viable option I found is to implement a "service mesh". I have seen that Calico, Istio, Linkerd are good options. But I don't know which one is the lightest as any of them have a lot of components that I won't really need.

If you have another recommendation, it is welcome.

I read:

- [What is pod to pod encryption in kubernetes? And How to implement pod to pod encryption by using mTLS in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881298/what-is-pod-to-pod-encryption-in-kubernetes-and-how-to-implement-pod-to-pod-enc)
- [How to configure Kubernetes to encrypt the traffic between nodes, and pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453187/how-to-configure-kubernetes-to-encrypt-the-traffic-between-nodes-and-pods)
- https://medium.com/@santhoz/nginx-sidecar-reverse-proxy-for-performance-http-to-https-redirection-in-kubernetes-dd9dbe2fd0c7

Comment: I would recommend istio or linkerd, there is the [newest](https://dzone.com/articles/a-kubernetes-service-mesh-tool-comparison-for-2020) comparison I could find. As far as I know calico is connected with istio if we're talking about tls. You're looking for any other component to use or just tls between pods?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very complete and it helped me a lot to understand what worked best for me.

Unfortunately the kluster is in eks with fargate, I was validating and there is a restriction in fargate for network administration, that prevents an inject from being done, both in Istio and in Linkerd

For now I am validating that another way I have to do the encryption between nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calico is an overlay network and CNI implementation. It won't automatically encrypt the communication between pods on its own, as far as I know.

Linkerd and Istio are service meshes which implement CNI to encrypt traffic with a CNI provider like calico, *but* a CNI provider is not required.

Linkerd will [automatically](https://linkerd.io/2/features/automatic-mtls/) encrypt traffic with mTLS out of the box.

I think Istio added that feature recently.

Linkerd is much easier to install and use, and its proxy is [faster and uses fewer resources](https://kinvolk.io/blog/2019/05/performance-benchmark-analysis-of-istio-and-linkerd/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very complete and it helped me a lot to understand what worked best for me.

Unfortunately the kluster is in eks with fargate, I was validating and there is a restriction in fargate for network administration, that prevents an inject from being done, both in Istio and in Linkerd

For now I am validating that another way I have to do the encryption between nodes

Comment: I also put your answer as correct, because it solves my original question